# too much recursion exception thrown by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I am using fileupload using codeigniter and jquery ajax. On saving other text and file, all things are saved however too much recursion error is thrown in console. The code format to save is as follows:

```
doc_submitform = function(){
        var frm=$('#frm_save_doc').validate({
            errorElement: "small",
            wrapper: "div",
            debug : true,
            onclick : false,
            onblur  : true,
            focusCleanup: true,
            rules: {
                doc_type:{
                    required:true,
                },
                file_upload:{
                    required:true,
                },
                remarks:{
                    //required: true,
                }
            },

            highlight: function(label) {

                $(label).closest('.control-group').addClass('error');
            },
            submitHandler : function() {
                var file_data =$('#file_upload').prop('files')[0];

                var form_data = new FormData();
                form_data.append('file', file_data);
                form_data.append('doc_type', $('#doc_type').val())
                form_data.append('remarks',$('#remarks').val())
                form_data.append('emp_id', $('#emp_id').val())
                form_data.append('doc_id', $('#doc_id').val())

                $.ajax({
                        url: SITE_URL+'hrm/employee/ajax/action/save_doc_details',  
                        dataType: 'json',  
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        data: form_data,                         
                        type: 'post',
                        success: function(response){
                            if(response.status == 200){
                                $docTable.fnDraw(false);                                
                            }

                            $('#frm_save_doc #cancel_btn').trigger('click');

                        }
                 });    

            }                           
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that line:

`$('#frm_save_doc #cancel_btn').trigger('click');`

`#frm_save_doc #cancel_btn` is not valid jQuery selector, if you want to specify  any number of selectors, you should use:

`$( "#selector1, #selector2, #selectorN" );`

Can you use just `#cancel_btn` instead? I think it should works.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. I was using such selectors because I had many view pages and previously the pages conflicted with each other so I added form id to distinguish the page.